# How to redirect non-existing subdomains in nginx to 404

Tags: nginx, dns, http-status-code-404, subdomain, digital-ocean

I have one valid subdomain on my site; it and the main domain work. But I was wondering, what if someone enters a bogus subdomain?

I have a rule like this:

```
# throw away all other subdomains
server {
  server_name ~^(.*)\.foo\.to$ ;

  return 301 https://foo.to/notfound;
}
```

I thought this would fix the problem but instead the browser complains: `DNS address could not be found.`

Sure, I suppose that makes sense. But why is it that when I go to a non-existent GitHub Pages subdomain (https://adfljaslfdjalsfdkjalfgsjklakfgjlajrgiajeroigjtaoi4jto.github.io/), *that* does send a 404? How do I emulate that?

Comment: You need to add a wildcard in DNS if you want to catch all names, so that they all resolve to the IP address of your webserver. But this is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Also, you should use a "catch-all" server, using the `default_server` attribute. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names)

Comment: You don't need a regex to catch all subdomains, using `server_name *.foo.to;` will do the same. Check [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone google to here:

After spent some time to research, I found it is quit easy.

First, we have to forbidden all server with wild match:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.example.com;
  return 404;
}
```

Then you can define all known subdomains as servers.